# Rails ActiveRecord Date Comparison Database Agnostic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, datetime, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to find a database agnostic way of comparing dates with active record queries. I've the following query:

```
UserRole.where("(effective_end_date - effective_start_date) > ?", 900.seconds)
```

This works fine on MySQL but produces an error on PG as the sql it generates doesn't contain the 'interval' syntax. From the console:

```
  ←[1m←[36mUserRole Load (2.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "user_roles".* FROM "user_roles" WHERE "user_roles"."effective_end_date" IS NULL AND ((effective_end_d
ate - effective_start_date) > '--- 900
...
')←[0m
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type interval: "--- 900
```

When I run this with the to_sql I option I get:

```
irb(main):001:0> UserRole.where("effective_end_date - effective_start_date) > ?", 900.seconds).to_sql
=> "SELECT \"user_roles\".* FROM \"user_roles\"  WHERE \"user_roles\".\"effective_end_date\" IS NULL AND (effective_end_date - effective_start_date) >
'--- 900\n...\n')"
```

All help appreciated.

Comment: That `UserRole.where(...)` doesn't match the SQL you dug out of your logs; and something is doing a `900.to_yaml` in the query from your logs and that doesn't make sense.

Comment: This is what is being generated. I haven't pasted the full rails error stack below this but can if that is useful. I have added a to_sql version so you can what that generates. Thanks for your help

Comment: Any idea where the `effective_end_date is null` is coming from? That YAMLization of `900.seconds` doesn't make any sense to me. And you're missing an `(` in your `.where`, copy'n'paste error? Are the `effective_start_date` and `effective_end_date` dates or datetimes/timestamps?

Comment: Hmmm. My queries using `.where(..., 900.seconds)` are also YAMLizing the 900, what sort of overly clever nonsense is Rails up to? [`seconds`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Numeric.html#method-i-seconds) actually returns an `ActiveSupport::Duration` when `900.seconds.class` says `Fixnum`. Sigh.

Comment: That's a good question - hadn't spotted the effective_end_date is null. It's coming from a default scope on the model. I'll re-run with it unscoped and see if it changes anything

Comment: You'll still get the YAML nonsense and date arithmetic problems. I'll give this a bit more thought later this afternoon. Any chance that you could include the `to_sql` output when using MySQL? I'm curious if the MySQL version will have the YAML nonsense too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `effective_end_date` and `effective_start_date` columns really are dates then your query is pointless because dates have a minimum resolution of one day and 900s is quite a bit smaller than 86400s (AKA `25*60*60` or 1 day). So I'll assume that your "date" columns are actually datetime (AKA timestamp) columns; if this is true then you might want to rename the columns to avoid confusion during maintenance, `effectively_starts_at` and `effectively_ends_at` would probably be good matches for the usual Rails conventions. If this assumption is invalid then you should change your column types or stop using 900s.

Back to the real problem. ActiveRecord converts Ruby values to SQL values using the [`ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Quoting#quote`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/quoting.rb#L8) method:

```
def quote(value, column = nil)
  # records are quoted as their primary key
  return value.quoted_id if value.respond_to?(:quoted_id)

  case value
  #...
  else
    "'#{quote_string(YAML.dump(value))}'"
  end
end
```

So if you try to use something as a value for a placeholder and there isn't any specific handling built in for that type, then you get YAML (a bizarre choice of defaults IMO). Also, `900.seconds` is an `ActiveSupport::Duration` object (despite what `900.seconds.class` says) and the `case value` has no branch for `ActiveSupport::Duration` so `900.seconds` will get YAMLified.

The PostgreSQL adapter provides its own `quote` in [`ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter#quote`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb#L430) but that doesn't know about `ActiveSupport::Duration` either. The MySQL adapter's [`quote`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb#L198) is also ignorant of `ActiveSupport::Duration`. You could monkey patch some sense into these `quote` methods. Something like this in an initializer:

```
class ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter
    # Grab an alias for the standard quote method
    alias :std_quote :quote
    # Bludgeon some sense into things
    def quote(value, column = nil)
        return "interval '#{value.to_i} seconds'" if(value.is_a?(ActiveSupport::Duration))
        std_quote(value, column)
    end
end
```

With that patch in place, you get intervals that PostgreSQL understands when you use an `ActiveSupport::Duration`:

```
> Model.where('a - b > ?', 900.seconds).to_sql
 => "SELECT \"models\".* FROM \"models\"  WHERE (a - b > interval '900 seconds')" 
> Model.where('a - b > ?', 11.days).to_sql
 => "SELECT \"models\".* FROM \"models\"  WHERE (a - b > interval '950400 seconds')"
```

If you add a similar patch to the MySQL adapter's `quote` (which is left as an exercise for the reader), then things like:

```
UserRole.where("(effective_end_date - effective_start_date) > ?", 900.seconds)
```

will do The Right Thing in both PostgreSQL and MySQL and your code won't have to worry about it.

---

That said, developing and deploying on different databases is a really bad idea that will make Santa Claus cry and go looking for some coal (possibly laced with arsenic, possibly radioactive) for your stocking. So don't do that.

If on the other hand you're trying to build database-agnostic software, then you're in for some happy fun times! Database portability is largely a myth and database-agnostic software always means writing your own portability layer on top of the ORM and database interfaces that your platform provides. You will have to exhaustively test everything on each database you plan to support, everyone pays lip service to the SQL Standard but no one seems to fully support it and everyone has their own extensions and quirks to worry about. You will end up writing your own portability layer that will consist of a mixture of utility methods and monkey patches.

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed answer (way beyond my current knowledge level - but I understand what you are saying). It is really useful to know that database-agnostic software is not a given with rails. I'm happy to stick with one DB but wanted to keep options open as far as possible. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Paul: Database-agnostic software exists in the same way that OS-agnostic software exists :)